# Проверка относительной ссылки jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть подобный список:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/about">About Me</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/user/cv">CV</a></li>
            <li><a href="/user/photo">Photo</a></li>
            <li><a href="/user/messages">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/settings">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

С помощью jquery(или js) нужно найти ссылку страницы в данный момент и выделить.

Проблема в том, что вот этот код:

```
$(function () {
    $('li a').each(function () {
        var link = window.location.href;
        $("a[href='+ link +']").css('font-weight', 'bold')
        });
    });
```

Код не работает, т.к. возвращается абсолютный адрес вроде `test.com/user/cv`

**Вопрос:** как-то обрезать ссылку до относительной и передать как переменную в поиск?

Можно и другой способ, только пожалуйста с объяснениями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `window.location.pathname`. Заодно не будет ни части с query, ни хеша.